# How to add a line break after each window.document.writeln

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to add a line break after each window.document.writeln?

I thought using .writeln as opposed to .write would do the trick but it only added a space.

```
for (var fizzCount = 1; fizzCount<=100; ++fizzCount) {
    if (fizzCount % 3 == 0)
        window.document.writeln("Fizz");
    else if (fizzCount % 5 == 0)
        window.document.writeln("Buzz");
    else if (fizzCount % 15 == 0)
        window.document.writeln("FizzBuzz");
    else 
        window.document.writeln(fizzCount);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eyLarL23/1/

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Is this a CodeCademy exercise?

Comment: Enclose your snippet with pre tag. check my answer

Comment: @Jenny Does my answer help? If so, please accept. Else, feedback please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember this [Codecademy lesson](https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/fizzbuzz/2/5) ☺.

Simply add a

```
+ "<br />"
```

to each of your `writeln()` statements.

Your code doesn't work because `writeln()` creates a `\n` line break instead of a `<br />`, so it is not represented as a line break.

For example:

```
for (var fizzCount = 1; fizzCount<=100; ++fizzCount) {
if (fizzCount % 3 == 0)
window.document.writeln("Fizz<br />");
else if (fizzCount % 5 == 0)
window.document.writeln("Buzz<br />");
else if (fizzCount % 15 == 0)
window.document.writeln("FizzBuzz<br />");
```

See updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyLarL23/2/).

**Extra Tip 1**

Also, since you're already using jQuery, you can simplify your `window.document.writeln()` statements to shorter jQuery statements like so:

```
var d = $("body");
for (var fizzCount = 1; fizzCount<=100; ++fizzCount)
    if (fizzCount % 3 == 0)
        d.append("Fizz<br />");
    else if (fizzCount % 5 == 0)
        d.append("Buzz<br />");
    else if (fizzCount % 15 == 0)
        d.append("FizzBuzz<br />");
```

**Extra Tip 2**

Your code doesn't print out "FizzBuzz" at multiples of 15: instead, it prints out just "Fizz" because it encounters the  `if(fizzCount % 3 == 0)` statement first. To fix this, put the `if(fizzCount % 15 == 0)` statement first so that it checks it first.

Therefore, the final (working) code would be:

```
var d = $("body");
for (var fizzCount = 1; fizzCount<=100; ++fizzCount)
    if (fizzCount % 15 == 0)
        d.append("FizzBuzz<br />");
    else if (fizzCount % 3 == 0)
        d.append("Fizz<br />");
    else if (fizzCount % 5 == 0)
        d.append("Buzz<br />");
    else
        d.append(fizzCount + "<br />");
```

See working example at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqL8mcpr/).

Comment: We can avoid break tag if we enclose with pre tag !

Answer (score 1):

Enclose with `<pre>` Tag. you will see the real behavior.

```js
    document.write('<pre>');
    for (var fizzCount = 1; fizzCount<=100; ++fizzCount) {
        if (fizzCount % 3 == 0)
            window.document.writeln("Fizz");
        else if (fizzCount % 5 == 0)
            window.document.writeln("Buzz");
        else if (fizzCount % 15 == 0)
            window.document.writeln("FizzBuzz");
        else 
            window.document.writeln(fizzCount);
    };
    document.write('</pre>');
```

Fiddle URL:
https://jsfiddle.net/eyLarL23/3/

Answer (score 0):

document.writeln already adds a line break. You don't see it because the default behaviour is to swallow /coallesce whitespace.

If you view the generated source of the page, there will be a new line on that text node.

If you want to see a newline on your page, use a br tag

```
window.document.writeln("Fizz" + "<br />");
```